# Ubuntu file system read-only after Windows system restore at previous point

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, fsck, root-filesystem, readonly

I am running Ubuntu 18-04 via WSL on a Windows Virtual Machine in Azure.
I needed to restore the machine to a previous point,
and what happened was that the Ubuntu file system is now read-only. 
When I run

```
dmesg
```

I have the following errors on the root file system

```
[25081.148359] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:5592: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
[25081.150048] EXT4-fs warning (device sdc): ext4_clear_journal_err:5594: Marking fs in need of filesystem check.
[25081.155917] EXT4-fs (sdc): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[25081.164175] EXT4-fs (sdc): Errors on filesystem, clearing orphan list.
[25081.164913] EXT4-fs (sdc): recovery complete
[25081.167250] EXT4-fs (sdc): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered. Quota mode: none.
```

Now I had the problem of running fsck on a mounted partition. 
Since it is a VM, I can’t use an external disk,
so the only idea I had was to install another Linux version. 
I installed SUSE Tumbleweed and attached the Ubuntu root partition with

```
wsl -d openSUSE-Tumbleweed --mount --vhd C:\Users\adm_difolco_e\Documents\Airflow\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2019.522.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\ext4.vhdx –bare
```

I followed the [WSL2 How-to:
Prepare and Attach Virtual Drives (VHD)](https://anthony-f-tannous.medium.com/wsl2-how-to-prepare-and-attach-virtual-drives-vhd-ac17b1fc7a61) tutorial for it. 
Now when I run

```
lsblk
```

I get

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 389.8M  1 disk
sdb    8:16   0     4G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc    8:32   0     1T  0 disk
sdd    8:48   0     1T  0 disk /mnt/wslg/distro
```

The command

```
df
```

shows nothing about sdc,
but when I run

```
sudo fsck -N /dev/sdc
```

I get:

```
fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext4 for /dev/sdc
```

Comment: You need to adjust your `/etc/fstab`. The UUID has been changed .

Answer (score 0):

It must have been something with SuSE Tumbleweed. I installed Ubuntu 20-04 and did the same passages as in the question and it all worked flawlessly.

Only the `fsck` command was different:

```shell
sudo e2fsck -y /dev/sdc
```